# Centering SVG text gradient in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, svg

I am having an issue getting my SVG text to center in both Firefox and Chrome. I have not yet bothered to check other browsers. I currently have it centered horizontally in Firefox but in Chrome it is off by a few pixels. I noticed in Chrome the text is not quite filling up the width of the `<svg>` element leaving space on the right side throwing off the centering. The vertical centering is also different by a few pixels on the bottom in Firefox. How can this be resolved? Not sure what I am doing wrong in my code. To see a live view of the issue go to https://wsplays-members.com/results/ in both browsers and look at the "OUR CERTIFIED RESULTS" title. Thanks in advance.

```css
.widget-title {
  border-bottom: solid 3px black;
  font-family: 'anton', sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 2px auto 0;
  background: url(images/lines.png) bottom repeat-x;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!--SVG TITLE HEADER-->
<div class="widget-title">
  <svg height="30px" width="270px" viewBox="0 0 100% 100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
          <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(226, 69, 38);stop-opacity:1" />
          <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(34, 34, 34);stop-opacity:1" />
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
      <text fill="url(#grad1)" x="0" y="97%">Our Certified Results</text>
      Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
    </svg>
</div>
<!--END SVG TITLE HEADER-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your `viewBox` is invalid.  You can't use percentage values in a `viewBox`.  Consequently it will be being ignored. But you don't need it anyway in your case.

Anyway, your problem is that you are centering the SVG in the `<div>` but you are not centering the text in the SVG.

If you want your text to be centred in your SVG, position it in the exact centre and use `text-anchor="middle"`.

In your case you will want to change the text element to:

```
<text fill="url(#grad1)" x="135" y="97%" text-anchor="middle">Our Certified Results</text>
```

In the example below I have increased the `width` of the SVG, and the text `x` position, because we have to use a wider font.

```css
.widget-title {
  border-bottom: solid 3px black;
  font-family: 'anton', sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 2px auto 0;
  background: url(images/lines.png) bottom repeat-x;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

svg {
  border: solid 1px green;
}
```

```html
<!--SVG TITLE HEADER-->
<div class="widget-title">
  <svg height="30px" width="450px">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
          <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(226, 69, 38);stop-opacity:1" />
          <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(34, 34, 34);stop-opacity:1" />
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
      <text fill="url(#grad1)" x="225" y="97%" text-anchor="middle">Our Certified Results</text>
      Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
    </svg>
</div>
<!--END SVG TITLE HEADER-->
```

Comment: Can't believe I was missing something so simple. Thank you very much for taking the time to help and explain. Learning a lot. :)